# Is there a way to have non-overlapping data point labels on a ternery plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I am trying to replicate a chart I found on FiveThirtyEight at https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-cable-news-reacted-to-the-cohen-hearing/. This shows a ternery plot where the location of the words in the 3 axis shows the proportion quoted that by that respective network.

I am currently using R, ggplot2 and more importantly ggtern (which I use extensively for ternery plots). However I have never found a way to make data labels on points **not** overlap. I have always hoped that ggtern would interact with ggrepel but sadly it doesn't (to my knowledge). **Is there any way to force these to interact, or find another way of doing this?**

Chart shown in link for clarity of what I'm after:
[image: FiveThirtyEight ternery example]

Example of my chart with words overlapping and looking bad:
[image: Bad ternery plot and bad visualization]

**EDIT**
Code to create my hideous chart:

```
    data <- data.frame(word = c("A","random","set","of","words","that","can","hopefully","help","someone","solve","my","issue","of","overlapping","labels","and","make","my","chart","readable","and","a","good","visualization"),
               axis1 = sample(1:100),
               axis2 = sample(1:100),
               axis3 = sample(1:100))

    ggtern(data = data,
        aes(x = axis1, y = axis2, z = axis3, colour = word, label = word)) +
      geom_point(size = 1) +
      geom_text()
```

Comment: can  you show the code/data for you chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you want the functionality as in `ggrepel` package. While ggrepel wont work here you can use `position_nudge_tern` and `check_overlap`:

```
word = c("A","random","set","of","words","that","can","hopefully","help","someone","solve","my","issue","of","overlapping","labels","and","make","my","chart","readable","and","a","good","visualization")
col = c("red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green","red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green","red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green","red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green","red")

n  = 25   #Number of Data Points
nv = 0.1  #Vertical Adjustment
pn = position_nudge_tern(y=nv,x=-nv/2,z=-nv/2)

data <- data.frame(x = sample(1:25),
               y = sample(1:25),
               z = sample(1:25), 
               label=word)

ggtern(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, colour = col, label = word)) +
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  theme_nomask() + #Allow Labels to Spool Over Edges
  geom_text(position=pn,aes(label=word),check_overlap=T, size=5)
```

Which will give you non-overlapping labels:[image]

Comment: This doesn't work alongside ggtern. I'm after something like ggrepel, but that correctly works on ternery plots.

Comment: True. Also, in your example graph they adjusted the position by changing the angle of text (e.g. it is not all horizontal)

Comment: @Peter : Is it ok now?

Comment: Sorry about this, been meaning to get ggrepel working with ggtern. Plenty of people have asked for it.

Comment: @Nicholas Hamilton Do you know if it is possible to adjust the angle in my example plot (like it was in cable news example of @Peter)?

Comment: As in angle of rotation of individual texts?

Comment: Yes, exactly: angle of rotation of individual texts.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton ggrepel and ggtern together is everything I need! It is the one (and only) short coming of ggtern, otherwise its excellent!